# Breaking an href text into multiple lines using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to break the hyperlink text stored in the variable "output" into multiple lines. I current have this:

```
var output = "";
output = output.concat("line 1");
output = output.concat("<br />");
output = output.concat("line 2");
output = output.concat("<br />");
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(output);
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = output;
a.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Unfortunately, the text of the break tag appears, and the lines don't actually break. I've also tried "\n" instead of the break tag, but didn't work. Any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply put `a.innerHTML = output` instead of

```
var linkText = document.createTextNode(output);
a.appendChild(linkText);
```

Corrected Version:

```js
var output = "";
output = output.concat("line 1");
output = output.concat("<br />");
output = output.concat("line 2");
output = output.concat("<br />");
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.innerHTML = output;
a.title = output;
a.href = "http://www.google.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `createTextNode` does exactly what it says. Html-code like `<br>` will not work here.

Either append textNodes for every line and create `<br>` elements in between

or simply use `a.innerHTML = output`;